# firebase deploy functions not working

Tags: firebase, npm, firebase-cli

It this the first time that this happend to me. I've tried to init firebase more than once, but still having the same results.

When I try to deploy functions with command:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

The console returns next:

```
=== Deploying to 'hay-equipo-3a19b'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix functions run build
npm ERR! missing script: build

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Usuario\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-01-24T21_36_36_260Z-debug.log

Error: functions predeploy error: Command terminated with non-zero exit code1
```

Here is my package.json of functions folder

```
{
  "name": "functions",
  "description": "Cloud Functions for Firebase",
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "firebase serve --only functions",
    "shell": "firebase experimental:functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase-admin": "~5.8.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^0.8.1",
    "nodemailer": "^4.4.2"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

The log file says

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   '--prefix',
1 verbose cli   'functions',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'build' ]
2 info using npm@5.5.1
3 info using node@v8.9.3
4 verbose stack Error: missing script: build
4 verbose stack     at run (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:151:19)
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\lib\run-script.js:61:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:115:5
4 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:402:5
4 verbose stack     at checkBinReferences_ (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:357:45)
4 verbose stack     at final (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:400:3)
4 verbose stack     at then (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:160:5)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\read-package-json\read-json.js:332:20)
4 verbose stack     at ReadFileContext.callback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\graceful-fs.js:78:16)
4 verbose stack     at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete] (fs.js:420:13)
5 verbose cwd C:\Users\Usuario\Projects\torneos-club-oeste
6 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.16299
7 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "--prefix" "functions" "run" "build"
8 verbose node v8.9.3
9 verbose npm  v5.5.1
10 error missing script: build
11 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: Please show the contents of your `firebase.json` file.  Did you modify it at all after the CLI created it?

Comment: I do not think you necessarily need the scripts being explicitly defined in your package.json if you have installed everything via npm correctly and initialised the project correctly. Is this a part of some larger ecosystem such as Angular CLI? Do you have any other packages or some relevant def files in the project? Are you sure you are in the functions directory when you deploy? Sounds to me like you are not. Change directory to navigate into the functions folder and run the command again. There should be no reason to run build for firebase functions.

Answer (score 0):

Seems if you just put a blank `"build"` entry into your `functions/package.json` file under 'scripts' then it solves this (well it did for me).

```
{
    "scripts": {
        "build": "",   <----- simply add this!
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```